# How to retrieve json data in restapi post method in server side of oracle apex?

Tags: json, rest, post, plsql, oracle-apex

Json data is as follows. This is output of `print(jsonEncode(requestData))`

`{"mData":{"L":2,"B":1,"D":1},"day":"2024-02-17 00:00:00.000Z"}`

flutter code

```
try {
http.Response response = await http.post(
Uri.parse(url),
headers: <String, String>{
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
body: jsonEncode(requestData),
);
```

I want to make some update operation with this values.

```
   update t1 set count = 2 where m_type='L' and day='2024-02-17'
   update t1 set count = 1 where m_type='B' and day='2024-02-17'
   update t1 set count = 1 where m_type='D' and day='2024-02-17'
```

I tried this but not works.

I faced `Status code: 555`

I can access bind variables like `{username: username, password: pass}` but can't access json as shown above.

I tried this in oracle apex.

```
    DECLARE
    p_m_type t1.m_type%TYPE;
    p_count t1.count%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..:mData.count LOOP
        p_m_type := :mData(i).meal_type;
        p_count := :mData(i).count;

        UPDATE t1
        SET count = p_count
        where day = :day
        AND m_type = p_m_type;
        
     END LOOP;
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISE;
    END;
```

`day` is a `DATE` type column.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**

[image]

I can access :day. I want to access mData also but don't know how.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should extract your data from json with JSON_TABLE() function:

```sql
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Select    jt.L, jt.B, jt.D, To_Date( SubStr(DAY_ID, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) "DAY_ID"
From      JSON_TABLE( '{"mData":{"L":2,"B":1,"D":1},"day":"2024-02-17 00:00:00.000Z"}',
                      '$'
                      COLUMNS ( L      Number(3)    PATH '$.mData.L', 
                                B      Number(3)    PATH '$.mData.B', 
                                D      Number(3)    PATH '$.mData.D', 
                                DAY_ID VarChar2(32) PATH '$.day' 
                              )
                    ) jt
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
         L          B          D DAY_ID  
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          1          1 2024-02-17   */
```

Don't know your table description, but the update statement could be something like this:

```sql
MERGE INTO your_table_name t
USING ( Select    jt.L, jt.B, jt.D, To_Date( SubStr(DAY_ID, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) "DAY_ID",
        From      JSON_TABLE( '{"mData":{"L":2,"B":1,"D":1},"day":"2024-02-17 00:00:00.000Z"}',
                              '$'
                              COLUMNS ( L      Number(3)    PATH '$.mData.L', 
                                        B      Number(3)    PATH '$.mData.B', 
                                        D      Number(3)    PATH '$.mData.D', 
                                        DAY_ID VarChar2(32) PATH '$.day' 
                                      )
                            ) jt
      ) x ON( --> your join condition <-- )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.COUNT = Case When t.M_TYPE = 'L' And  t.DAY = To_Date(x.DAY_ID, 'yyyy-mm-dd') Then L
                              When t.M_TYPE = 'B' And  t.DAY = To_Date(x.DAY_ID, 'yyyy-mm-dd') Then B
                              When t.M_TYPE = 'D' And  t.DAY = To_Date(x.DAY_ID, 'yyyy-mm-dd') Then D
                        Else t.COUNT
                        End
WHERE --> your where conditions if needed <--
```

Comment: I mentioned the table columns. Check the update statement in my code.

Comment: @FarhanaAkhter We don't know description nor content of the table that should be updated. If there are some rows in it and/or there are multiple json data to be processed you should fill in the gaps - 1. your real table name, 2. join conditions between your table and JSON_TABLE() rows and 3. Where conditions (if needed) that will filter rows to be updated.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. I provide sample JSON. For this JSON which column will be updated for which table I mentioned using regular SQL. You can give me solution for this only. If you provide hard solution that will be better for me to understand now. after understanding then I can make it for generic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FarhanaAkhter Don't know your t1 table content - just that it has columns count and m_type and day. Are there any other columns, what is the primary key, any other indexes or constraints. Is this the only json to process or are there more json rows. Just don't know. If it is only json to process and if you MERGE INTO t1 t AND if you put  1=1 as join's ON condition AND without where clause this will updaate all rows puting value into count column depending on m_type column value (if L then vaalue of L, if B then value of B ... from json)

Comment: primary key(m_type, day). There no same m_type for a day. day is a date column. I have only this JSON. If I can know to handle this I hope I can do it for any JSON.

Comment: @FarhanaAkhter 1. MERGE INTO t1 t     .....    ....    2.  ...  ... ON( t.day = x.day ).    3. No need for Where clsuse. Using query results with one row having date and three values for L, B, D. When merged to the table it will update all rows for the date in json. Case will do the rest.

Comment: Bind variables are used by their name. How you access the JSON data come from client side is missing here. You passed the JSON into JSON_TABLE(). This JSON comes from client side it is dynamic.

Comment: @FarhanaAkhter Againm there is no data  on your actual context, and it would take too much space for all steps from the begining that should be done. Read the docs :  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql#create-post-web-services  ....

Comment: @FarhanaAkhter Regarding client side - that is a thing for you to do. Update statement will do the job in the database. The command could  be created dynamicaly and run/posted in different ways and/or you could create a plsql package/procedure to be called from client with json passed as parameter.

Comment: I think I can't make you understood my problem.

Comment: `
BEGIN
UPDATE orders SET note=:day WHERE id=23403;
        :status := 200;
        :location := 23403;
        sys.htp.prn(sys.htf.escape_sc('Successful'));
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        :status := 400;
        :location := NULL;
        sys.htp.prn(sys.htf.escape_sc(sqlerrm));
END;
`

I can access :day. I want to access mData also.

I modified the question also